# How to queue functions with variables properly

Tags: jquery

I'm having trouble getting functions to run one after another.  It seems that often the first function doesn't execute.  I'd prefer to run the functions one by one in a call back or queue method but I can't get it working properly.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

```
        function sts_lookup(e) {
            $("#sts_lookup").on().load('sts_lookup.jsp', {'wks': e});
        }
        function machine_lookup(e) {
            $("#machine_lookup").on().load('machine_lookup.jsp', {'wks': e});
        }
        function warranty_lookup(e) {
            $("#warranty_lookup").on().load('warranty_lookup.jsp', {'wks': e});
        }
        function cc_lookup(e) {
            $("#cc_lookup").on().load('cc_lookup.jsp', {'wks': e});
        }
        function do_da_checks(e) {
            sts_lookup(e);
            machine_lookup(e);
            warranty_lookup(e);
            cc_lookup(e);
        }
```

Comment: what does the console log say?

Comment: `.load` takes an `onComplete` function as welll... http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Console says nothing.  The first function works properly if bound to a click event or running by itself.  When tied to all 4 the first does not run.

Answer (score 0):

You could return [Promises](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/promises) from every function and once the load function completes, resolve the promise. Use the "then" callback to execute the next function.